# Open PDF file with Save As option

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to open PDF file with Save As option which is not working below code always downloads the PDF file

Below is the cod eon handler.asp file. I want to pass file name as `querystring` in this case i am using static file name in code.

Be is the code example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;

public partial class en_PdfHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string filename = Request.QueryString["fn"];
                string path = Server.MapPath("1.pdf");
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);



                if (buffer != null)
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=1.pdf");
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                    Response.End();
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.Close();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want save as option. What you get now? And what's your browser?

Comment: i think you may change **attachment** to **inline** in Content-Disposition.

Comment: It just download file directly. I want Save As option so that user can either open it there in pdf reader or save it to folder of there choice.

Comment: Your code works fine in my sample. In chrome and IE both have save as option

Comment: @MichaelMao, May be it is the browser setting which is making it like that.